# Can type arguments be made deduceable for function templates using std container?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, function-templates

I found this implementation of a few common features of functional programming, e.g. map / reduce:
(I'm aware stuff like that is aparently coming or partially present in new C++ versions)

[github link](https://gist.github.com/dant3/fe28dd98539c4b671990)

A part of the code:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
U foldLeft(const std::vector<T>& data,
           const U& initialValue,
           const std::function<U(U,T)>& foldFn) {
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator Iterator;
    U accumulator = initialValue;
    Iterator end = data.cend();
    for (Iterator it = data.cbegin(); it != end; ++it) {
        accumulator = foldFn(accumulator, *it);
    }
    return accumulator;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
std::vector<U> map(const std::vector<T>& data, const std::function<U(T)> mapper) {
    std::vector<U> result;
    foldLeft<T, std::vector<U>&>(data, result, [mapper] (std::vector<U>& res, T value)  -> std::vector<U>& {
        res.push_back(mapper(value));
        return res;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Usage example:

```
std::vector<int> biggerInts = map<int,int>(test, [] (int num) { return num + 10; });
```

The type arguments T,U have to be fully qualified for this to compile, as shown in the example, with e.g. map< int,int >( ... ).
This implementation is for C++11, as mentioned on the linked-to page.

Is it possible with newer C++ versions (or even 11) now to make the use of this less verbose, i.e. making the types U,T deduce automatically?
I have googled for that and only found that there is apparently some improvement for *class* template, as opposed to function template, argument deduction in C++17.
But since I only ever used templates in a rather basic manner, I was wondering whether there is something in existence that I'm not aware of which could improve this implementation verboseness-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More general templates make template argument deduction easier.

One principle: it is often a mistake to use a `std::function` as a templated function's parameter. `std::function` is a type erasure, for use when something needs to store some unknown invokable thing as a specific type. But templates already have the ability to handle any arbitrary invokable type. So if we just use a generic `typename FuncT` template parameter, it can be deduced for a raw pointer-to-function, a lambda, or another class with `operator()` directly.

We might as well also get more general and accept any input container instead of just `vector`, then determine `T` from it, if it's even directly needed.

So for C++11 I would rewrite these:

```
// C++20 is adding std::remove_cvref, but it's trivial to implement:
template <typename T>
using remove_cvref_t =
    typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;

template <typename Container, typename U, typename FuncT>
remove_cvref_t<U> foldLeft(
           const Container& data,
           U&& initialValue,
           const FuncT& foldFn) {
    remove_cvref_t<U> accumulator = std::forward<U>(initialValue);
    for (const auto& elem : data) {
        accumulator = foldFn(std::move(accumulator), elem);
    }
    return accumulator;
}

template <typename Container, typename FuncT>
auto map(const Container& data, const FuncT& mapper)
    -> std::vector<remove_cvref_t<decltype(mapper(*std::begin(data)))>>
{
    using T = remove_cvref_t<decltype(*std::begin(data))>;
    using ResultT = std::vector<remove_cvref_t<decltype(mapper(std::declval<const T&>()))>>;
    ResultT result;
    foldLeft(data, std::ref(result), [&mapper] (ResultT &res, const T& value)  -> ResultT& {
        res.push_back(mapper(value));
        return res;
    });
    return result;
}
```

See the [working program on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ae459a9e3a5bfe2).

There was one unfortunate thing about the old `map`: it potentially copied the result vector at every iteration. The `=` in `accumulator = foldFn(accumulator, *it);` is a self-assignment, which might do nothing, or might allocate new memory, copy contents, then free the old memory and update the container. So instead I've changed the `U` for `foldLeft` in this case to a `std::reference_wrapper`. The `=` in that case will still "rebind" the wrapper to the same object, but that will at least be quick.

In C++14 and later, you could do away with finding `T` within `map` by using a generic lambda: `[&mapper] (std::vector<U>& res, const auto& value)` ...

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite *map* signature to be:

```
template <typename T, typename M, typename U = decltype(std::declval<M>()(T{}))>
std::vector<U> map(const std::vector<T>& data, const M mapper)
```

then `T` will be deduced as `value_type` of vector's items.

`M` is any callable object.

`U` is deduced as return type of `M()` functor when called for `T{}`.

Below

```
std::vector<int> biggerInts = map(test, [] (int num) { return num + 10; });
                              ^^^^ empty template arguments list
```

works fine.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/tRN3Yd)

Comment: Should also be noted that this already works in C++11, so the author just chose to not implement it that way for some reason.

Comment: I'd change `T{}` to `std::declval<const T&>()`, both in case `T` isn't default-constructible, and in case `M` is strangely overloaded to give different result types for `T&&` and `const T&`.

Comment: This did the trick and I upvoted it. After some hesitation and hovering over the accept checkmark it read "... or the most helpful". Since the other reply explained/mentioned some things that weren't on my radar yet with regards to understanding all of this, I chose to "accept" that one.